# Breeze.js - + Facing issue while accessing service metata

Tags: breeze

Breeze.js - + Facing problem while accessing service metata.

Request for metadata is sent to 
`http://mylocalmachine:4625/WcfDataService1.svc/Metadata`

but metadata is getting published at `http://mylocalmachine:4625/WcfDataService1.svc/$Metadata`

Comment: how can I change this service url to http://mylocalmachine:4625/WcfDataService1.svc/$Metadata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Breeze client must be configured to communicate with your remote service. As I read your question, it appears that you're trying to reach an **OData** data source whose data service name is "*http://mylocalmachine:4625/WcfDataService1.svc*".

If so, you'll have to tell Breeze to switch from its *default* **Web Api dataService adapter** to the **OData dataService adapter**. Do that during your application bootstrapping with a line such as:

```
breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance("dataService", "OData");
```

Now, when you run your app and look at the network traffic, you should see that Breeze requests metadata with something like

```
http://mylocalmachine:4625/WcfDataService1.svc/$Metadata
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a prerequisite JavaScript library that you will need to include on the page in order to use the OData adapater.

It's mentioned in the documentation:- [dataJS](http://datajs.codeplex.com/).

Hope this helps.